# C# - Set value of an inherited static property on child and call it depending child type

Tags: c#, .net, performance, inheritance

I'm trying to have something looking like this :

```
class SerialEquipment
{
    private int baudrate;
    ......

    public SerialEquipment(int baudrate)
    {
        this.baudrate= baudrate;
    }

    public int Baudrate{ get => baudrate; set => baudrate= value; }
    ......

    public static void IdentifyEquipment<EquipmentType>()
    {
        int baudrate = (int)typeof(EquipmentType).GetProperty("Baudrate", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null, null);
        ........
    }
}

class EquipmentTypeA: SerialEquipment
{
    private static readonly int baudrate = 9600;
    ......
    public EquipmentTypeA() : base(baudrate) { }

    public static new int Baudrate{ get => baudrate}
    ......
}

class EquipmentTypeB : SerialEquipment
{
    private static readonly int baudrate = 38400;
    ......
    public EquipmentTypeB () : base(baudrate) { }

    public static new int Baudrate { get => baudrate }
    ......
}
```

But the purpose of inheritance is to avoid redundancies and I can't find something better for my use. I can't find a way to have only one declaration. So is there a better way to implement this ?

**EDIT 03/01/2018 :**

The function to identify an equipment looks like this using static :

```
public static List<String> IdentifyEquipment<EquipmentType>()
{
    List<String> wantedEquipmentList = new List<String>();

    int baudrate = (int)typeof(EquipmentType).GetProperty("Baudrate", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null, null);
    String identificationCommand = (int)typeof(EquipmentType).GetProperty("Baudrate", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null, null);
    String correctIdentificationResponse = (String)typeof(EquipmentType).GetProperty("CorrectIdentificationResponse", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(null, null);

    foreach (String aSerialPort in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {    
        SerialPort deviceInTest = new SerialPort(aSerialPort, baudrate);
        deviceInTest.Open();

        deviceInTest.WriteLine(identificationCommand);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        string result = deviceInTest.ReadLine();

        if (result.StartsWith(correctIdentificationResponse))
        {
            wantedEquipmentList.Add(aSerialPort);
        }     
    }

    return wantedEquipmentList;
}
```

And here the new implementation regarding Bruno Belmonde solution :

```
class DeviceIdentifier
{
    private List<DeviceFactory> factories = new List<DeviceFactory>();
    public void AddDeviceType(DeviceFactory factory) => factories.Add(factory);
    public ISerialDevice BuildDeviceByIdentification(String comPort, int baudrate, String identificationCommand, String identificationResponse) => factories.FirstOrDefault(deviceFactory => IdentifyEquipment(comPort, baudrate, identificationCommand, identificationResponse))?.Builder();

    private bool IdentifyEquipment(String comPort, int baudrate, String identificationCommand, String identificationResponse)
    {
        bool foundIt = false;
        SerialPort deviceInTest = new SerialPort(comPort, baudrate);
        deviceInTest.ReadTimeout = 200;
        deviceInTest.Open();

        try
        {
            deviceInTest.WriteLine(identificationCommand);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            string result = deviceInTest.ReadLine();
            if (result.StartsWith(identificationResponse))
            {
                foundIt = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //........
        }

        deviceInTest.Close();
        return foundIt;
    }
}

// MAIN
DeviceIdentifier deviceIdentifier = new DeviceIdentifier();
List<EquipmentTypeA> typeAList = new List<EquipmentTypeA>();

deviceIdentifier.AddDeviceType(new DeviceFactory
{
    Baudrate = 9600,
    IdentificationCommand = "You are ?",
    IdentificationResponse = "Type A",
    Builder = () => new EquipmentTypeA(9600)
});

foreach(String aSerialPort in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
{
    ISerialDevice identifiedObject =  deviceIdentifier.BuildDeviceByIdentification(aSerialPort, 9600, "You are ?", "Type A");

    if (identifiedObject != null)
        typeAList.Add((EquipmentTypeA)identifiedObject);
}
```

Comment: The first question which comes to mind is how are you going to use it? The answer will vary depending on the use case. Overriding static method is very likely to be a bad choice as it won't work if you have any polymorphic collection (or any polymorphic declaration)

Comment: You only have a couple of options 2,3,4,6,10 for vehicle wheels...  Just use an enum for them... *shrug*

Comment: @BrunoBelmondo The value wheelsNumber in this example correspond to the default baudrate of different kinds (Child class) of  Serial Equipments (Base class). I'm using the baudrate and many other static properties to first identify wich equipment i'm talking to and then I start using it.

Comment: @KevinCook As I said its just an example, my application is not about vehicles so my property can have random values. Moreover i don't think an enum would change anything if i want to access the specific value of child class without creating my object i will still need to do it as static.

Comment: If "you are talking to an equipment" then you are very likely to have an instance of it. Why use static field instead of instance field? This is where I need the usage to answer...

Comment: @BrunoBelmondo You connect to the computer many devices that uses Serial communication on RS232 or USB. When you start the software, you can't know if COM3 is DeviceTypeA or COM4 is DeviceTypeB. Which is why I need to identify all DeviceTypeA devices by knowing its default baudrate, command to identify it and it response to that command. So if I can get a correct response from COM3 I create an instance of DeviceTypeA.

Comment: This is quite wrong.  Use a virtual property or method, `public virtual int GetBaudrate()`.  Now you can ensure that a derived class can provide a different baudrate.  Some caution is appropriate perhaps, serial port devices are not very virtual.  There are 6 properties you need to get right and the proper way to read and write the device, following the underlying protocol, is rarely the same either.  Creating a class hierarchy for devices that just don't behave similar is a mistake.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you suggest? I need to control all of them together and I know all the characteristics of the devices i will be dealing with. The goal was to have a class for every equipment to coordinate them from an interface.

Comment: Hmm, dealing with the quirks of just one serial device can be quite a time-sink.  Tough project.  Use the virtual keyword to get this right.  Favor each class having its own SerialPort object so you can cut down on the amount of glue.

Comment: Usually, if you're fighting the type system or inventing concepts that don't really exist (inherited static), it's usually an indication that trying to build your classification scheme into the type system is the wrong approach.

Comment: Maybe another language would be more appropriate? I'm doing this with C# because I need a functional interface in no time and it suits me in many other aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your design to the following:

```
public interface IDevice
{
    void WhateverIWantToDoWIthDevice();
}

public class DeviceIdentifier
{
    private List<DeviceFactory> factories = new List<DeviceFactory>();
    public void AddDeviceType(DeviceFactory factory) => factories.Add(factory);
    public IDevice BuildDeviceFromBaudrate(int baudrate) => factories.FirstOrDefault(f => f.BaudRate == baudrate)?.Builder();
}

public class DeviceFactory
{
    public int BaudRate { get; set; }
    public Func<IDevice> Builder { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your main, just add the known device like this

```
deviceIdentifier.AddDeviceType(new DeviceFactory
{
    BaudRate = 12,
    Builder = () => new DeviceOfTypeA()
});
```

so when something is connected, you test the baudrate versus the device identifier which will give you an instance of device, assumign that it has one factory matching.

You can elaborate from here on the test required to identify...

**In the end, remember that static has to be manipulated with caution and that too much static is usually a bad smell. Static overriding is even worse**

Comment: I will try this implementation and let you know.

Comment: I don't really get all the concepts used in your code. I never used this object construction process (Builder Pattern ?). And especially this line : "public IDevice BuildDeviceFromBaudrate(int baudrate) => factories.FirstOrDefault(f => f.BaudRate == baudrate)?.Builder();"

Can you give a detailed explanation?

Comment: this lines is looking through all the factories and get the first one matching the given Baudrate. THen if none is available it returns null. Otherwise it calls the Builder function (chich wraps a call to the constructor of the type held by the factory)

Comment: I think i'm starting to understand the process, but how do I call "BuildDeviceFromBaudrate" ?

Comment: well, I suppose that somewhere in your code, you watch for a device to be inserted then you get the effective baudrate of the device and then you just have to call deviceIdentifier.BuildDeviceFromBaudrate(effectiveBaudrate). Of course you first have to create the deviceIdentifier and add all the known devices first

Comment: I edited the question to show you how I used to identify my equipments when it worked with static fields. Before identifying the equipments the only thing that I have is a list of COM ports (COM1, COM2, etc.), not knowing if COM1 is the Equipment A or B. So if I'm looking for all the Equipments A, I will have to open a serial communication at the default known baudrate for all Type A and send it a command and see if i can get the answer the equipment is supposed to send back.

I implemented your example on the edited question.